# Optimizing array mutation in Clojure

Tags: arrays, optimization, clojure

Having read a few blog posts on the subject, I have found that mutating an array in Clojure like this:

```
(defn m [xs ys] 
  (dotimes [i (count xs)] 
    (aset #^ints ys (int i) 
    (int (* (int 3) (int (aget #^ints xs (int i))))))))
```

where `(def xs (into-array Integer/TYPE (range 1000000)))` and `(def ys (into-array Integer/TYPE (range 1000000)))`

took an average of 14ms according to Criterium, whereas the Java to do the same,

```
public static int[] m(int[] x, int[] y)
{
  for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    y[i] = 3*x[i];
  return y;
}
```

takes an average of 800us. **

Am I doing all I can to makes things go fast and Is there any further I can go down the optimization path ?

** I timed these using Criterium with `(report-result (bench (m xs ys )) :verbose)` and `(report-result (bench (. Test m xs ys)) :verbose)`

Comment: if you are doing a lot of this kind of stuff, you should probably be looking at `core.matrix` and/or `vectorz-clj` rather than hand-coding mathematical operations on arrays.

Comment: yeh, now that they exist certainly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this on Clojure 1.3:

```
(set! *unchecked-math* true)

(defn m [^longs xs ^longs ys]
  (dotimes [i (count xs)]
    (aset ys i
      (* 3 (aget xs i)))))
```

Comment: back on my work machine I get 2ms for the above Clojure and 1.95ms for Java using longs for everything. So they are the same. Interestingly I get 800us for Java using ints on this machine even though it's the same JVM and Linux version (no difference between ints and longs for Clojure though).

Comment: (set! *unchecked-math* true) - does that mean all math operations will be unchecked globally, or only this namespace ? How to control the scope ?

Comment: I believe it's per namespace. But you can just turn it off after the block of code where you want unchecked match. It's just a compiler flag.

Comment: Since it's earmuffed, I think the best way to use it is to place your critical defns inside a `(binding [*unchecked-math* true])`. But anyway, great to see Clojure coming through like this! Clojure primitive support covers only longs and doubles, so that's why it's the same with ints, I'd say.

Comment: @Hendekagon notice that `(set! ....)` is at the same level as the `defn`, so it gets executed at compile-and-load time. Threading issues are not of relevance.

Comment: one final question, since Clojure only supports type hinting for ^longs,^floats,^doubles etc - 1d primitive arrays, there's no efficient way to generalize this example to multidimensional arrays right ?

Comment: (class (make-array Long/TYPE 2 2)) ;; => [[J, so type hint is ^"[[J"

Answer (score 5):

If you want speed, you need to enter the world of primitives and not leave it until you're done. It's no use starting with a boxed `Integer i` and then converting it to a primitive at each use site. Maybe you can make `dotimes` produce ints (type-hint the declaration of `i`), but not sure. What I know works is a `loop-recur` construct with primitive initializers of loop vars: `(loop [i (int 0)] ... (recur (unchecked-inc i))`. Also, in you example you have `(int 3)`. You need to `let` that in advance so as not to repeat the unboxing in each iteration.

BTW, you can use `(int-array (range 1000000))` to create your initialized array and just `(int-array 1000000)` for the empty one.

**UPDATE**

As of Clojure 1.3, with its enhanced support for primitives, most of what I wrote above doesn't apply anymore. `dotimes` already uses primitive arithmetic, so all you need to write to get the full performance is

```
(dotimes [i (alength ^ints xs)] 
  (aset ^ints ys i (unchecked-multiply (aget ^ints xs i) 3)
```

Basically, no `int` constructors necessary, and use `unchecked-multiply`.

Comment: ok so I'm on a different machine now but the results so far: original is 36ms, (let [z (int 3)] (dotimes... is 37ms, (int (count xs))... is 35ms, (both previous 2) 37ms, removing type hints (int i) is also 37ms and loop-recur form is 37ms too (not surprizing as dotimes is implemented with loop-recur)

Comment: The issue is not whether it's implemented with `loop-recur` (of course it is) but whether the looping var is bound to a primitive or boxed number. Turns out that in Clojure 1.3 it as a primitive var, so what I proposed to implement in raw loop-recur amounts to exactly the same thing as just using plain dotimes. However, you need to use longs instead of ints. Never force clojure to coerce from long back to int.

Comment: I'm testing this too. I gain 25% advantage by using unchecked-multiply in place of *. RE: longs -> ints -- are you using a 64-bit VM? On my box the ints and longs performs the same, so no gain either way.

Comment: To get further with this, try to check the generated bytecode and compare with Java. I don't know whether you can check that without gen-class, but it should be possible.

Comment: I am using a 64-bit VM and yes ints & longs run the same speed for me too. This https://gist.github.com/2397907 is the fastest implementation so far for me ... update oooh! unchecked-multiply gives 6.5ms https://gist.github.com/2397946

Comment: Just a slight hint: instead of `#^` it's enough to use just `^`. That's as of Clojure 1.2.

Comment: ^ok :-)   ... that's due to copy&pasting bits of code from blogs which are from different times

Comment: and finally, I compare with the Java implementation above, and that's 6ms on my laptop here, compared with 6.3ms for the last Clojure implementation (standard deviation for Clojure 563us vs 30us for Java)

Comment: Really, so your conclusion is that they are on a par? So the 0.8 ms you got before no longer applies? I should change my answer, then. It might be important if anyone else sees this later.

Comment: well the first Java timing (800us) was on my PC at work which is very fast, these latest results are on my home laptop

Comment: My testing shows 2.1 ms for Java against 16.5 ms for Clojure (best times).

Comment: I am testing Clojure from the REPL and Java from Eclipse, so your test might be better. Though, even when I start the VM in Eclipse with -client, the result is still the same.

Comment: I am testing both from the REPL as I wanted to factor-out any possible differences due to other things, and use Criterium for both

Comment: CORRECTION: I was using `int[]` and now switched to `long[]`. A different story: now it's 5.2 seconds best time for Java.

Comment: well, I'm tired but I do appear to be getting the same times for both - off to bed now, maybe I'm doing it wrong but that's what it looks like now

Comment: update: see above thread - Clojure and Java *are* comparable - rejoice!